# Do I get the production back if I buy the building with gold?

Tags: civilization-6

I started building a stadium, because I was getting low on amenities. I chose the city where the stadium would have the most impact (4 cities within 6 tiles), rather than the city with the highest production, so the construction has been going on for a while. It's 72% complete and I need 7 more turns to finish it.

I now have the gold to buy the stadium and I could really use the extra amenities, but I'm worried that I will just lose all the production I've spent on it so far. I've already checked that the price to buy the building isn't reduced by the production already spent, so unless the production is kept for whatever the city produces next, it will be lost.

Did anyone try this and knows what happens?

Comment: Pretty sure the gold you spend to complete also goes down for every turn left in building. So there would be no production to give back, since you are buying the production left, not the total production. Been a while, could be wrong.

Comment: @Fredy31 Pretty sure the cost doesn't go down in Civ-6. It did in previous civs, but this changed in VI. I've run many times into this trap, and a change in buying cost would certainly have tipped me off.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, any production already invested in a building is lost when you buy the building. You will need to pick your build order carefully to avoid loosing any production.

In your particular scenario, the loss in production might very well be worth it if the amenities you gain will allow you to get back to normal growth and production rates in nearby cities. You will need to weigh your options.

Additionally, with 72% done and 7 turns to go, you might want to look into assigning trade routes to your city or manually picking worked tiles to acquire extra production and finish sooner. In general, without knowing your game's economy, 72% sounds like a lot to just go buying the building.

If all fails, you could also look into unlocking your government and switching in policy cards that will give you a temporary boost to your amenities.